# I want to get java jar but I just get zip from apache

Tags: java

I'm new to this things, and I go to the website and download a zip file, but I don't know how to import it, I heard that I need a jar, but I don't have it, where can I get it?
[image]

Comment: Is there a jar inside the zip? Sometimes, rename a zip file to jar. If the organization of the file is right, you would be able to run it.

Comment: Have you looked what's inside the zip?

Comment: there some folders and files, I'll show you a pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible you downloaded the sources of a project? 
If so you need to

1. extract your zip to a directory
2. install Apache maven if not yet done
3. open a command prompt and enter "mvn package" to build the project.

If successful, a new target directory will be created and your jar will be in it.

Comment: I tried to download the package on http://hc.apache.org/, then I don't know how to do

Comment: download the binary zip instead of the source zip. http://www.trieuvan.com/apache//httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.5-bin.zip

Comment: Thank you so much, so what's the difference between that two kind of type?

Comment: the source zip contains the uncompiled source code of the library. So if you want to use it as an executable you need to compile it. The binary zip contains already the compiled/build library. If you only want to use it and not modify it, the binary will do.

Comment: I understand, thanks so much, it really helps me a lot